# globally enable RabbitMQ quorum queues in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

Is there any possibility to define *every queue* to be provisioned as a quorum queue instead of a classic queue?

`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.quorum.enabled=true` is per each binding, looking for a global approach like `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.quorum.enabled=true`